# Calling database.php from external script CI

Tags: codeigniter

So I have a script that is called by an AJAX request, and it is in a folder named 'ajax' at the root of the CI install. I have this code at the top of my ajax file:

```
define("BASEPATH", "../../system/");
include("../../application/config/database.php");
```

So it grabs the database.php file successfully, but it is telling me that there is 'no database selected'. Why?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to make your Ajax call to a standard CI controller?

Comment: How would I do that if it's in a directory outside the app folder?

Comment: Awesome! I figured it out. Do you think it's okay to just output the data directly from the model? That way I don't have to send it to the controller and then possible to another output, or is it really bad practise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outputting data within models breaks the conventional structure of an mvc for which codeIgniter aims to achieve. But then mvc is a design pattern not strictly a standard so you are not hurting anyone but yourself and others who will take after you or work your code in the future.

Like AndrewR suggested, why not make the ajax call to a controller [again since that is the convention of mvc] ? if its gonna be outside the app folder then perhaps it should not be accessible through the web browser.

Also you could grab an instance of the codeigniter's global object as in `$_CI =& get_instance();` and load the database object like this `$db = $_CI->load('database');`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks mate. I ended up using the way Andrew suggested, and I sure am glad I did! Makes a whole lot more sense! Means I can deny access to the ajax controller to sneaky users as well. Got it all working nicely! The reason I didn't want to use the conventional method is just because it would save me time, as there is a LOT of database queries to run, etc.